# Access variables from Go in Python and vise versa

Tags: python, database, go

My engine is written in GO and I already use SQLITE because I generate some plots that I want to display in a GUI. So far, I think that GO does not have a mature GUI package, so I am building my GUI in Python, with Tkinter that I am familiar with.

When I run my engine in GO with a certain flag, it calls the Python script for the GUI and it generates the content on the background continuously. There are certain modes that the GO engine runs and normally I have to change them by going back to the terminal that runs GO (different plots etc).

What I want, is to create action buttons in my Python GUI that they will change those flags/variables values and the GO script will generate different plots for example, without me going back to the terminal that runs the GO engine and manually do it.

So far, the only implementation from my side, was to create another SQLITE database and save my settings there. Then, when I press an action button at my GUI, it changes the value at my Settings Database and GO reads this value from there all the time, instead of waiting me to input it.

Is there any better way of doing it, passing a variable value(flag etc) from one programming language to the other(Python-GO) without using a database?

The variables that I am changing from the GUI are strings in general and I am asking this question because I think that it is a waste of resources to do it the way I do it.

Comment: There are practically infinite ways to do this. At start time you could pass values by file, env var, or CLI argument; at runtime you could pass via stdin, socket, or TCP, using anything from RPC to REST. What's best for your situation depends on your situation.

Comment: You can also let the Python script start the Go program and use OS signals to, well, signal a settings update.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers. They are really very beneficial for helping me to understand how to it the "right way", depending on the situation of course.

Comment: You might consider to just use https://github.com/nsf/gothic which provides native Go bindings to Tk — what Tkinter does for Python.